# AWS Route 53 Subdomain Pointing to Different IP Address

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I'm having some problems setting up a subdomain using Route 53.  I have two physical instances running.  One is for production and one is for staging/testing.  Of course each instance has its own Elastic IP.

The production box is running just fine.  Its the staging one that is the issue.  I've set up the subdomain DNS entries in Route 53 and modified my http.conf settings in Apache on the staging machine but can't get the subdomain to connect.

Here are the Route 53 entries for the PRODUCTION instance:

[image]

And here are the Route 53 entries for the STAGING instance:

[image]

And here are the apache httpd.conf entires on the STAGING Machine for the VirutalHosts:

[image]

When I use the elastic IP for the staging machine it works perfectly.  And just to be clear:  In the Route 53 entries for the staging machine I am using the staging IP address for the A records.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the first screenshot (PROD) show all existing records or there is more below?

Comment: Why do you have two hosted zones?  If the domain name is the same, you need only one; if for some reason you *want* two, the main zone has to be configured to delegate the subdomain to the other zone.

Comment: Dusan - yes that first screenshot is everything.

Comment: And Michael I tried it both way.  All in one and separate and neither one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I figured out what it was.  The domain was registered with a third party and the name servers hadn't been transferred over to Route 53's.  Once I did that everything is working fine.

And I have it all under one Hosted Zone too.